# How can I fix the weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting

What's going on here?

[image]

I had done all my weight painting but I ruined it by using symmetrize. As you can see in the pic, the selected bone is moving the other arm too. I already made sure it's not weight painted and I fixed the vertex group to not include that arm. What else do I need to fix?

Also, can anyone give me a quick way to mirror weight painting already applied to one side to the other? I asked it here a while ago:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47671/how-to-mirror-weight-painting-already-applied-to-one-side

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple solution. I had to remove the weight painting from areas connected to the upper arm too, not just the upper arm. When I symmetrized, it copied all the weight painting on my right to left but kept it assign to the same bone/vertex group.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  If you found that symmetrize copied the weights from one side's bones to the other side's geometry, it could be that the naming convention of your bones wasn't conducive to right->left conversions.  Best bet is to re-examine your bone naming convention for future symmetrize operations.

Comment: @MikeBelanger Really? I used riggify with automatic weights (which I then modified with weight painting). I believe that does make it conducive to right to left conversions, correct? Maybe it's the way I used symmetrize? I already had a full object with both sides, but lost symmetry in one area so I thought I could use symmetrize to restore it. It did but it ruined the weight painting it seems. Thank you. (I learned a better way to restore symmetry using shape keys)

Comment: I don't think riggify re-names the initial bones you target, does it?

Comment: I used the bones that riggify gives you. The metarig. The all have the "L" and "R" at the end if that's what you mean.